# Browser adds extra closing tags

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #5A3895;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
  border: 3px solid #999999;
}

.inside-dropdown-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #5A3895;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
  border: 3px solid #999999;
}

.dropdown-button:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
}

.dropdown-button:hover {
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
}

.inside-dropdown-button:hover>.inside-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
}

.inside-dropdown-button:hover {
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
}

.name-label p {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.name-label {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header {
  border: 1.5px solid #999999;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:not(.impressum-link):not(.inside-dropdown-button) {
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #5A3895;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-width: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
}

.impressum-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: #5A3895;
  float: right;
  background-color: #FDEBCF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-width: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="link">
<span>Home</span>
</button>
  </div>


  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-button">
<span>Publications</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button type="button" class="inside-dropdown-button">
      <span>Recent Publications</span>
      <div class="inside-dropdown-content">
        <p>year</p>
        <a href="/">A link to whatever</a>
      </div>
    </button><a href="/">Other Publications</a></div>
  </button>

</div>

<div class="name-label">
  <p>Website</p>
</div>

<button type="button" class="link impressum-link">
<span>Impressum</span>
</button>

</div>
```

I put in everything as I don't know what causes the problem.

I want to have the `inside-dropdown-button` inside of `dropdown-content`, but the browser (tested on Firefox and Chrome) seems to change

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="dropdown-button">
<span>Publications</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button type="button" class="inside-dropdown-button">
      <span>Recent Publications</span>
      <div class="inside-dropdown-content">
        <p>year</p>
        <a href="/">A link to whatever</a>
      </div>
    </button><a href="/">Other Publications</a></div></button>
    
  </div>
```

to:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="dropdown-button">
<span>Publications</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    </div></button><button type="button" class="inside-dropdown-button">
      <span>Recent Publications</span>
      <div class="inside-dropdown-content">
        <p>year</p>
        <a href="/">A link to whatever</a>
      </div>
    </button><a href="/">Other Publications</a></div>
```

Notice the extra `</div></button>` before `<button type="button"` in the 5th line. This extra `</div>` causes there to be to many `</div>`'s, messing up the header class, and putting `impressum-link` outside of the header. Why is this and how do I get around it?

If I change it in the Browser, it works, but when I copy the code out of the browser to the script and remove the extra tags, it puts them in again.

Comment: On [the MDN <button> page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), the "Permitted content" section shows what can go inside a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `button` cannot contain another `button` so the browser assumes you have made an error and closes it for you.

Also note that `button` elements cannot contain links (and vice versa).

> [****Permitted content****](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)
>
> Phrasing content but there must be **no Interactive content**